# Granting permission to domain user for folder not working

Tags: vbscript, icacls

I'm converting my code to use `icacls` and currently following this tutorial: https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html.

On this part,

> Grant the user jdoe rights to create, edit and delete files in the
>   folder C:\demo\example\, but prevent deletion of the folder itself:
>
> :: First remove inheritance and grant admins Full control to the top
>   folder icacls "C:\demo\example" /inheritance:r /grant:r
>   administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
>
> :: Grant Modify + Delete Child to subfolders and files only icacls
>   "C:\demo\example" /grant:r ss64Dom\jdoe:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M,DC) /T
>
> :: Grant Read/Execute, Write and Append to the top level folder icacls
>   "C:\demo\example" /grant:r ss64Dom\jdoe:(RX,WD,AD)
>
> :: if any pre-existing subfolders Grant admins Full control icacls
>   "C:\demo\example" /grant:r administrators:(OI)(CI)(F) /T

, I was able to get the right results for the first instruction but the second one doesn't work for me. I tried to change the `M,DC` part with `F` but it doesn't work as well.

This is my code.

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim objShell,objFSO, ProgramFiles, X, Y, intRunError, strFolders,strFiles, strNTGroup
Dim strFolder, strFile, strUserName, strEveryone, strDomain

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strFolders = Array(_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder3",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder2",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder")

strFiles = Array(_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_file.txt",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_file2.txt")

'User's User Name
strDomain = "Domain"
strUserName = strDomain & "\User"
strEveryone = "Everyone"

WScript.Echo "Set permissions for", strUserName, vbCRLF

'Assign User Permissions to Folders.
For X = 0 to Ubound(strFolders)
    strFolder = strFolders(X)
    If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
        WScript.Echo "Folder: " & strFolder
        'intRunError = objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c Echo Y| cacls " & strFolder & " /E /C /G " & strUserName & ":F", 2, True)
        objShell.Run "icacls " & strFolder & " /inheritance:r /grant:r administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)", 2, True
        intRunError = objShell.Run("icacls " & strFolder & " /grant:r " & strUserName & ":(OI)(CI)(IO)(M,DC) /T", 2, True)

        If intRunError <> 0 Then
            Wscript.Echo "Folder ErrCode: " & intRunError
            Wscript.Echo "Error assigning permissions for user " _
            & strNTGroup & " to folder " & strFolder
        End If

    Else
        WScript.Echo "Folder " & strFolder & " not found"
    End If
Next
```

I'm running it on my local Windows 7 PC btw.

This is how my current code looks like.

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim objShell,objFSO, ProgramFiles, X, Y, intRunError, strFolders,strFiles, strNTGroup
Dim strFolder, strFile, strUserName, strUName, strEveryone, strDomain, intRunError2, intRunError3

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strFolders = Array(_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder3",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder2",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder")

strFiles = Array(_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_file.txt",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_file2.txt")

'User's User Name
strDomain = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERDOMAIN%" )
strUserName = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
strUName = strDomain & "\User" 
strEveryone = "Everyone"

WScript.Echo "Set permissions for", strUName, vbCRLF

'Assign User Permissions to Folders.
For X = 0 to Ubound(strFolders)
    strFolder = strFolders(X)
    If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
        WScript.Echo "Folder: " & strFolder
        intRunError = objShell.Run("icacls " & strFolder & " /inheritance:r /grant:r administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)", 2, True)

        If intRunError <> 0 Then 'If no error, proceed
            Wscript.Echo "Folder Error1: ", intRunError
            Wscript.Echo "Error assigning admin permissions for user " _
            & strUName & " to folder " & strFolder
        Else
            Set intRunError2 = objShell.Exec("icacls " & strFolder & " /grant:r " & strUName & ":(OI)(CI)(NP)(IO)(M,DC) /T", 2, True)

            Wscript.Echo "Exit code: " & intRunError2
            Wscript.Echo "ErrMsg: " & intRunError2.StdErr.ReadAll

            If intRunError3 <> 0 Then
            Wscript.Echo "Folder Error3: " & intRunError2
            Wscript.Echo "Error assigning permissions for user " _
            & strUName & " to folder " & strFolder

            Wscript.Echo "Exit code: " & intRunError2
            Wscript.Echo "ErrMsg: " & intRunError2.StdErr.ReadAll
            End If
        End If

    Else
        WScript.Echo "Folder " & strFolder & " not found"
    End If

    WScript.Echo "-------------------"
Next

Wscript.Echo "Done setting folder permissions", vbCRLF

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

The first `objShell.Run` works. On the following `objShell.Exec`, no error appears but it doesn't do anything as well.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Today found about `Exec`. I used `Exec` and found out I have Access is denied.

Comment: Are you running your program "as administrator"?

Comment: Hi, create a folder like share Set the rights to any User, create inside this your sub share With group you need to Set this should work

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've run it as administrator but still the same result. The permissions doesn't get applied to the folder.

Comment: @djdomi I'm not trying to create a share folder. I'm trying to create a logon script that would change a user's permission upon login. I wasn't able to make the logon part work but I'm making the logic work first as it is more important.

Comment: Well, what are the existing permissions on the folder?

Comment: At first, the folder got the SYSTEM, domain user, and Administrator with full permission but no special permission.